# How to get multiple value with token_get_values()?

Tags: 6, tokens, entities

I have a field which accepts unlimited values so the values of the field get saved in an array.  If I use `token_get_values()` to get the corresponding field value, I only get the first element of the array.

How can I read the whole array value or get an imploded string of values with `token_get_values()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, using `token_get_values()`. The code that is returning the value of the token for a CCK field uses just the first value of the field. The function that gets the value of a token for a CCK field ([content_token_values()](http://drupalcode.org/project/cck.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/includes/content.token.inc)) contains the following code. (See in particular the code between `// [1]`.)

```
  $content_type = content_types($node->type);
  $node->build_mode = 'token';
  $node->content = array();
  content_view($node);
  // The formatted values will only be known after the content has been rendered.
  drupal_render($node->content);
  content_alter($node);

  $field_types = _content_field_types();
  foreach ($content_type['fields'] as $field_name => $field) {
    $items = isset($node->{$field_name}) ? $node->{$field_name} : array();
    $function = $field_types[$field['type']]['module'] . '_token_values';
    if (!empty($items) && function_exists($function)) {
      // [1]
      $token_values = (array) $function('field', $items, $options);
      // [1]
      foreach ($token_values as $token => $value) {
        $tokens[$field_name .'-'. $token] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
```

The function called in `$function('field', $items, $options)` is, for a text field, [text_token_values()](http://drupalcode.org/project/cck.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/modules/text/text.token.inc), which contains the following code.

```
  if ($type == 'field') {
    $item = $object[0];

    $tokens['raw']  = $item['value'];
    $tokens['formatted'] = isset($item['view']) ? $item['view'] : '';
    return $tokens;
  }
```

Despite `content_token_values()` passing all the CCK field values, the function just uses the first value.